# Is it possible to figure out if IE redownloads Silverlight xaps from C# or powershell code?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, networking, silverlight

We still have Silverlight (sad story) and I need to write a smoke test that checks if IE redownloads XAP files when accessing the site after deployment. Redownloading  XAPs means there is some kind of configuration/deployment issue and it is bad.

The code is either C# or Powershell and must be running without human intervention, of course. It runs on a dedicated test runner machine where I can install Fiddler, for example.

However, using Fiddler or any global proxy for that matter is not ideal, since the same test runner is used to smoke test different sites deployed within our cloud. It is possible, though. Additional complication is that Fiddler would have to install its SSL certificates in order to decrypt the HTTPS traffic. In short, I am not sure if this is the right way. Plus it is unclear to me how to automate the steps:

1. Install certificate
2. Start capture
3. Fetch the captured traffic
4. Stop capture
5. Remove certificate

So, I am looking for an advice on how to do it, not necessarily using Fiddler or global HTTP proxy in general. Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

This test is already on the manual smoke test list. We are automating these tests and now is the turn of this one.

Comment: That is an excellent question. And a good writeup. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if we will be able to provide a definitive, provable answer, since it could have any number of solutions. 

Comment: And for it's worth: My suggestion would be if it is becoming too difficult to automate, to not automate then but instead make it part of your QA manual test case list. Not great, but there is a balance between the difficulty and repeatability of automation versus how much time it saves. Unless you're deploying this very often, like daily—but if you're still stuck on Silverlight my guess is your shop/customer isn't that on the ball. (Again, this isn't "best practice" advice, but practical 'get it done' advice for a project that may not be meeting every other best practice out there anyway.)

Comment: Already tested locally. But we wish to automate it. We can install anything on the test runner, if needed.

Comment: Might be better to ask this at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to test IE's behavior, which isn't practical.

For example, IE may be configured to always delete its cache on exit, and so re-downloading the XAP is expected behavior in a subsequent request.

I would actually try to test the hosting HTML page and/or the HTTP response.

For example, you can request the web page programmatically using a `WebRequest` and then check to see if the response has content expiration or cache control in its header, which tells the browser if it should cache the page or not.

You may also want to check the `<param />` child element of the `<object />` element on the web page whose `source` value has a URL.

The browser will cache the XAP file given the URL is the same as it was before.
So you can check if that value changes with a subsequent request.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg701782(v%3Doffice.14):
*...the browser will cache this .xap file just as it would any other file based on the cache policies that are set.*

Here's some sample C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://example.com/SilverlightHostingPage.html"));

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string cacheControlHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Cache-Control");
// TODO: check header value

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
string xapUrl = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//object/param[@name='source']").Attributes("value").Value;
// TODO: check xap url
```

Comment: Hmm, so what you are saying is that the XAP caching rules are exactly the same as for any other HTTP resource? and hence can be understood by parsing the HTTP response? I still prefer to test it through the browser assuming it is not configured to delete its cache on exit.

Comment: Yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg701782(v%3Doffice.14) "the browser will cache this .xap file just as it would any other file based on the cache policies that are set."

Comment: It means the test must analyze the HTTP response and figure out what the browser would do. Need to see if this is an easy test. Can you arrange your response as an answer, so I could credit it? Would be nice if you could provide some operational details.